# Android - Handling Spotify Async Image Download

Tags: android, asynchronous, spotify

I am developing an app in android which do multiple async connections to spotify and to my own server. My problem is that when I load the tracks I have to wait for the images to show in a ImageView. This is the app flow:

1. On the App run I download a general Playlist to begin the player with the first track.
2. (First async call) Then I download the album image.
3. (Second async call) At the same time of the second step I connect to my server and download a set of tracks (the Spotify URI).
4. When the async connection to the server I create an ArrayList made of Track objects. Every Track object has its own properties and calls an async task (DownloadImageTask) which downloads the album image for the track.
5. Just before of creating the ArrayList (while the images are being downloaded), I create an adapter with 2 TextView and an ImageView and asign the ArrayList as data for the adapter of the ListView (MainActivity).

Just here comes my problem. I try to save as a property of the Tracks the ImageView, in order to, when I receive the DownloadImageTask, asign the Bitmap received to the setImageBitmap function of the ImageView. But right there the ImageView is null, so, I can't asign the Image.

I was thinking on a callback when the list is created for sending the pointer to the ImageView, but can't find the way. Otherwise I could test another way if you give me an idea.

I can post the code on demand (It is pretty much code, and I don't want to make a great question with a lot of unuseful code).

Thanks in advance.

**Adapter code:**

```
public class ContinueListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<MyTrack> {

    private int layoutResource;

    public ContinueListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<MyTrack> tracksList){
        super(context, layoutResource, tracksList);
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
        }

        MyTrack theTrack = getItem(position);

        if (theTrack != null) {
            TextView userData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userData);
            TextView trackData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trackData);
            ImageView albumImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumImage);

            userData.setText("Petición de: " + theTrack.getUserName());
            trackData.setText(theTrack.getSongName()+" / "+theTrack.getAlbumName());
            albumImage.setImageBitmap(theTrack.getBitmap()); //I did this first with the hope of getting the image when it was downloaded, no way.
            theTrack.setImageView(albumImage); //So I passed the ImageView to a property of the Track object, but the ImageView reference is null
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you do not use Glide or Picasso or something else to do the image loading/caching/handling?

Comment: I dont know those libraries. I am pretty new to Android, so my knowledge is short. How can those libraries can help in my problem?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dealing with images use Glide or Picasso libraries. You will have background downloading, image caching, scaling and all the stuff handled by these libraries in usually 3-5 lines of code.

> But right there the ImageView is null, so, I can't asign the Image

Even if your target image view at the moment download finishes is gone, you most likely will want to show the image again soon (i.e. user will get back to you activity or list row would be scrolled back to the screen) - since there's cache, it will be served from there next time you refer the same image.

Comment: I will try it right now, u can be sure. But just a question, I am posting the code for the adapter creation in my question. How can i reference this from glide `Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);`with the ImageView of the list?

Comment: In your adapter - `getView()`/`onBindViewHolder()` depending if you use listview or recyclerview

Comment: Thats what I did (see the code on top), but It is still null reference.

Comment: Are you saying that you are refer `imageview` that is present in your row's layout and you get `null`?

Comment: Yes, thats what I am saying. I save a reference to the ImageView in the Track object for using it on demand, but I get null.

Comment: Do not store any reference in Track. This is wrong approach - Track should not know much about UI. Once you started i.e. Glide and referred valid ImageView you do not need to care any more.

Comment: Ok, let me a while to implement Glide in my project and I will tell you.